# LG monitor frequently goes blank

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors, macos-bigsur, lg-monitor

I have an LG 34" UW (ultra wide) monitor attached via USB-C to HDMI connector to either an M1 MacBook Air or Intel-based MBP. In either case, the monitor randomly goes blank after 5-60 minutes. I can either disconnect/reconnect the adapter or even lock the laptop (with hot corner), sleep the main display and unlock to reactive the external monitor. I have tried adaptors from Moskin and Anker with the same results. I'm running Big Sur 11.4 on both machines.

I've tried capturing logs in the Console app but without success. I can't even find what to search for when it happens. There are no entries for the adaptor or the monitor.

I'd welcome any troubleshooting advice to see what the problem is before I return this monitor for a different brand. TIA.

Comment: Does it have DisplayPort… or anything better than HDMI? Try that instead. [You didn't tell us what model display, btw]

Comment: I'm loath to buy/try a third solution, but I saw one on Amazon for about $15. I'll update the post after I try it. Fingers crossed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem was to not use HDMI and switch to DisplayPort. It seems that the HDMI connection on the LG monitor might be flaky since I've used HDMI before without issues.

Kudos to @Tetsujin for the suggestion.